# Conditional Update Record Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, sql-update

I would like to ask if its possible to put a Conditional for the `UPDATE`. First of all I have two tables.

**`billing_records`**:

```
brecord_id (PK)
date_billed
monthly_rent
water
electricity
total_payable
status (paid/unpaid)
```

**`payment_records`**

```
payment_id (PK)
date
type_payment (cash/cheque/on_bank)
amount_payable
change
balance
cheque_number
bank_number
brecord_id (FK)
```

I would like the code to go like this during insertion records on database:

```
IF balance==0 
     UPDATE status to 'paid' from billing_records TABLE
else
     UPDATE total_payable(of billing_records) = balance(of payment_records)
```

During submit button I have two actions to make, to insert data in `payment_records` and `UPDATE billing_records`. I don't have problems inserting data in payment records, *only* updating the billing_records.

I'm having trouble in this line on my Controller

```
//  4. call model to save input to database table

$this->m_account_statement->insertPayableRecords($data);

$this->m_account_statement->changeStatusToPaid($brecord_id);
```

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
public function managePayment($brecord_id=0){

    if($this->_submit_validate_payment($this->input->post('type_payment'))===FALSE){

        $row = $this->m_account_statement->payableRecord($brecord_id);

        $data['amountPayable'] = $row->result();
        $data['brecord_id'] = $brecord_id;

        return $this->load->view('admin/vrecord_payment',$data);

    } else {

        // 2. get the inputs    

        $data['payment_id'] = $this->input->post('payment_id');
        $data['amount_payable'] = $this->input->post('amount_payable');
        $data['amount_received'] = $this->input->post('amount_received');
        $data['type_payment'] = $this->input->post('type_payment');
        $data['cheque_number'] = $this->input->post('cheque_number');
        $data['bank_number'] = $this->input->post('bank_number');           
        $data['balance'] = $this->input->post('balance');       
        $data['change'] = $this->input->post('change');
        $data['brecord_id'] = $this->input->post('brecord_id');
        $data['date'] = $this->input->post('date_transaction');     

        //  4. call model to save input to database table

        $this->m_account_statement->insertPayableRecords($data);

        $this->m_account_statement->changeStatusToPaid($brecord_id);

        //  5. confirmation of registration

        $this->session->set_flashdata('message',' Successfully Record Payment');

        redirect('caccount_statement/displayTenants');

    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function changeStatusToPaid($billing_id)
{
    $this->db->query("UPDATE billing_record SET status = 'paid' WHERE brecord_id = $billing_id");
}

public function insertPayableRecords ($data){

    if($this->db->insert('payment_record', $data)){
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to put a condition you can use this flow.

```
if balance==0 

//then fetch a record for status
//means run a query to get status

//now update

else 
// select some different values for update  
// now update query with fetched values
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function managePayment($brecord_id=0){
    //check if id is present or not like this:
    if ($brecord_id > 0) {//Update
        // ... put your update code ...
    } else { //Add
        // ... put your add code ...
    }
}
```